# On Swipe to delete and IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
line 42
```

at 42 line I have

```
        bind(items[position])
```

Myadapter

```
class RvNotesAdapter: ListAdapter<NoteData, RvNotesAdapter.NotesViewHolder>(DiffUtilCallback()) {

    var items = emptyList<NoteData>()


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): NotesViewHolder {
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        return NoteItemLayoutBinding.inflate(inflater, parent, false)
            .let(::NotesViewHolder)
        setListData(items)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: NotesViewHolder, position: Int): Unit = with(holder) {
        itemView
        bind(items[position])
    }

    inner class NotesViewHolder(val layout: NoteItemLayoutBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(layout.root) {
        fun bind(item: NoteData) = with(layout) {

            val title: MaterialTextView = layout.noteItemTitle
            val content: TextView = layout.noteContentItem
            val date: MaterialTextView = layout.noteDate
            val parent: MaterialCardView = layout.noteItemLayoutParent
            val markWon = Markwon.builder(itemView.context)
                .usePlugin(StrikethroughPlugin.create())
                .usePlugin(TaskListPlugin.create(itemView.context))
                .usePlugin(object : AbstractMarkwonPlugin() {
                    override fun configureVisitor(builder: MarkwonVisitor.Builder) {
                        super.configureVisitor(builder)
                        builder.on(
                            SoftLineBreak::class.java
                        ) { visitor, _ -> visitor.forceNewLine() }
                    }
                })
                .build()

            getItem(position).let { noteData ->

                parent.transitionName = "recyclerView_${item.id}"
                title.text = item.title
                markWon.setMarkdown(content, item.content)
                date.text = item.date
                parent.setBackgroundColor(item.color)
            }
            itemView.setOnClickListener {

                val action = ViewPagerFragmentDirections.actionViewPagerFragmentToSaveUpdateFragment2()
                    .setNote(item)
                val extras = FragmentNavigatorExtras(parent to "recycler_View_${item.id}")
                //hidekeyboard
                Navigation.findNavController(it).navigate(action, extras)

            }
            content.setOnClickListener {
                val action = ViewPagerFragmentDirections.actionViewPagerFragmentToSaveUpdateFragment2()
                    .setNote(item)
                val extras = FragmentNavigatorExtras(parent to "recycler_View_${item.id}")
                //hidekeyboard
                Navigation.findNavController(it).navigate(action, extras)
            }
        }
    }
//        getItem(position).let {noteData ->
//        holder.apply {

//            parent.transitionName="recyclerView_${noteData.id}"
//            title.text = noteData.title
//            markWon.setMarkdown(content, noteData.content)
//            date.text=noteData.date
//            parent.setBackgroundColor(noteData.color)

//            itemView.setOnClickListener {
//
//                val action = ViewPagerFragmentDirections.actionViewPagerFragmentToSaveUpdateFragment2()
//                    .setNote(noteData)
//                val extras = FragmentNavigatorExtras(parent to "recycler_View_${noteData.id}")
//                //hidekeyboard
//                Navigation.findNavController(it).navigate(action, extras)
//
//            }
//            content.setOnClickListener {
//                val action = ViewPagerFragmentDirections.actionViewPagerFragmentToSaveUpdateFragment2()
//                    .setNote(noteData)
//                val extras = FragmentNavigatorExtras(parent to "recycler_View_${noteData.id}")
//                //hidekeyboard
//                Navigation.findNavController(it).navigate(action, extras)
//            }
//        }
//        }
//    }

    fun getPositionAt(position: Int): NoteData {
        return items[position]
    }

    fun setListData(list: List<NoteData>) {
        this.items = emptyList()
        this.items = list
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }


}
```

fragmentNotesManager

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class NotesManagerFragment @Inject constructor() :
    BaseFragment<FragmentNotesManagerBinding, NotesManagerViewModel>(
        FragmentNotesManagerBinding::inflate
    ) {
    override val vm: NotesManagerViewModel by viewModels()
    private lateinit var rvNotesAdapter: RvNotesAdapter

    override fun onCreate(
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        exitTransition = MaterialElevationScale(false).apply {
            duration = 350
        }
        exitTransition = MaterialElevationScale(true).apply {
            duration = 350
        }
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        rvNotesAdapter = RvNotesAdapter()
        recyclerViewDisplay()
        collectNotesItems()
        observerDataChanges()
        //Check this
        lifecycleScope.launch {
            activity!!.window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS)
            activity!!.window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS)
            activity!!.window.statusBarColor = Color.parseColor("#9E9D9D")
        }
        // do zmiany navigation
        val navHostFragment =
            activity!!.supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainerView) as NavHostFragment
        val navController = navHostFragment.navController

        layout.addNoteFab.setOnClickListener {
            layout.appBarLayout.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            navController.navigate(ViewPagerFragmentDirections.actionViewPagerFragmentToSaveUpdateFragment2())

        }

        layout.innerFab.setOnClickListener {
            layout.appBarLayout.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            navController.navigate(ViewPagerFragmentDirections.actionViewPagerFragmentToSaveUpdateFragment2())
        }
        collectNotesItems()
//        collectNotesItems()
//        observerDataChanges()
        //implements search here

        layout.search.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
            override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
                layout.noData.isVisible = false
            }


            override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
                if (s.toString().isNotEmpty()) {
                    val text = s.toString()
                    val query = "%$text%"
                    if (query.isNotEmpty()) {
                        // livedata with observe to change
                        vm.searchNote(query).let {

                        }

                    } else {
                        collectNotesItems()
                        // obs
                    }
                } else {
                    collectNotesItems()
                    //obs
                }
            }


            override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {

            }

        })

        layout.search.setOnEditorActionListener { v, actionId, _ ->
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH) {
                v.clearFocus()
                // hide keyboard
            }
            return@setOnEditorActionListener true
        }

        layout.rvNote.setOnScrollChangeListener()
        { _, scrollX, scrollY, _, oldScrollY ->

            when {
                scrollY > oldScrollY -> {
                    layout.chatFabText.isVisible = false
                }
                scrollX == scrollY -> {
                    layout.chatFabText.isVisible = true
                }
                else -> {
                    layout.chatFabText.isVisible = true
                }
            }
        }

    }

    private fun swipeToDelete(rvNote: RecyclerView) {
        val swipeToDeleteCallBack = object : SwipeToDelete() {
            override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int) {
                val positionAdapter = viewHolder.layoutPosition
                val positionRoom = rvNotesAdapter.getPositionAt(positionAdapter).id
                val note = rvNotesAdapter.currentList[positionAdapter]

                val noteResponse = NoteDataDetailsResponse(
                    id = note.id,
                    title = note.title,
                    content = note.content,
                    date = note.date,
                    color = note.color
                )
                // val noteToDelete


                var actionBtnTapped = false

                vm.deleteNote(note).let {rvNotesAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(positionRoom)}

//                observerDataChanges()
//                collectNotesItems()
                layout.search.apply {
                    //hidekey
                    clearFocus()
                }
                if (layout.search.text.toString().isEmpty()) {
                    collectNotesItems()
                }
                val snackBar = Snackbar.make(
                    requireView(), "Note Deleted", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG
                ).addCallback(object : BaseTransientBottomBar.BaseCallback<Snackbar>() {
                    override fun onDismissed(transientBottomBar: Snackbar?, event: Int) {
                        super.onDismissed(transientBottomBar, event)
                    }

                    override fun onShown(transientBottomBar: Snackbar?) {
                        transientBottomBar?.setAction("UNDO") {
                            vm.saveNote(noteResponse)
                            actionBtnTapped = true
                            layout.noData.isVisible = false
                        }

                        super.onShown(transientBottomBar)
                    }
                }).apply {
                    animationMode = Snackbar.ANIMATION_MODE_FADE
                    setAnchorView(R.id.add_note_fab)
                }
                snackBar.setActionTextColor(
                    ContextCompat.getColor(
                        requireContext(),
                        R.color.yellowOrange
                    )
                )
                snackBar.show()
            }

        }
        val itemTouchHelper = ItemTouchHelper(swipeToDeleteCallBack)
        itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(rvNote)
    }

    private fun observerDataChanges() {
        vm.getActualState()
        // again with observer
        if (vm.noteDataList.value.isNotEmpty()) {
//            collectNotesItems()
            rvNotesAdapter.submitList(vm.noteDataList.value)
//        rvNotesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    }

    private fun initItemsRecyclerView() {
        swipeToDelete(layout.rvNote)
        layout.rvNote.adapter = rvNotesAdapter
    }

    private fun recyclerViewDisplay() {
        initItemsRecyclerView()
        when (resources.configuration.orientation) {
            Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT -> setUpRecyclerView(2)
            Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE -> setUpRecyclerView(3)
        }
    }

    private fun setUpRecyclerView(spanCount: Int) {
        layout.rvNote.apply {
            layoutManager =
                StaggeredGridLayoutManager(spanCount, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL)
            setHasFixedSize(true)
//            rvNotesAdapter = RvNotesAdapter()
//    rvNotesAdapter.stateRestorationPolicy = RecyclerView.Adapter.StateRestorationPolicy.PREVENT_WHEN_EMPTY
//            adapter = rvNotesAdapter
            postponeEnterTransition(300L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            viewTreeObserver.addOnPreDrawListener {
                startPostponedEnterTransition()
                true
            }
        }
//        collectNotesItems()
    }
    private fun collectNotesItems() {
        vm.noteDataList.collectWith(viewLifecycleOwner) {
            if(it.isEmpty()) {
                Log.d("collect", " empty $it")
                rvNotesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
            } else {
                Log.d("collect", "NOT empty $it")
                rvNotesAdapter.items = it
                rvNotesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

NotesManagerViewMOdel

```
@HiltViewModel
class NotesManagerViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val application: Application,
    private val addNotesItemsUseCase: AddNotesItemsUseCase,
    private val deleteNotesItemsUseCase: DeleteNotesItemsUseCase,
    private val getNotesItemsUseCase: GetNotesItemsUseCase,
    private val searchNotesItemUseCase: SearchNotesItemUseCase,
    private val updateNotesItemsUseCase: UpdateNotesItemsUseCase
) : BaseViewModel() {
    val noteDataList = MutableStateFlow<List<NoteData>>(emptyList())

    init {
        getActualState()
    }
    fun getActualState() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            getNotesItemsUseCase.build(Unit).collect {
                noteDataList.value = it
                Log.d("newNoteData", "${noteDataList.value}")
            }
        }
    }

    fun updateNote(existingNoteData: NoteData) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            updateNotesItemsUseCase.create(existingNoteData)
            getActualState()
        }
    }

    fun deleteNote(existingNoteData: NoteData) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            deleteNotesItemsUseCase.create(existingNoteData)
            getActualState()
        }
    }
    fun saveNote(newNoteData: NoteDataDetailsResponse) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            addNotesItemsUseCase.create(newNoteData)
            Log.d("newNoteData", "$newNoteData")
        }
    }

    fun searchNote(query: String) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            searchNotesItemUseCase.create(query)
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to get my actual data after deleting and additionaly I don't get my data when I enter my fragment ( it is one of three fragments (in the list) in viewpager)

When I go to another fragment which is not related with viewpager and come back it works, after it I have my data displayed:
for example going to SaveUpdateFragment

```
class SaveUpdateFragment @Inject constructor() :
    BaseFragment<FragmentSaveUpdateBinding, NotesManagerViewModel>(
        FragmentSaveUpdateBinding::inflate
    ) {
    override val vm: NotesManagerViewModel by activityViewModels()
    private lateinit var navController: NavController
    private val currentData = SimpleDateFormat.getInstance().format(Date())
    private var note: NoteData? = null
    private var result = ""

    private var color = -1
    private val args: SaveUpdateFragmentArgs by navArgs()
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val animation = MaterialContainerTransform().apply {
            drawingViewId = R.id.fragmentContainerView
            scrimColor = Color.TRANSPARENT
            duration = 300L
        }
        sharedElementEnterTransition = animation
        sharedElementReturnTransition = animation
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        val navHostFragment =
            activity!!.supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainerView) as NavHostFragment
        val navController = navHostFragment.navController

        ViewCompat.setTransitionName(
            layout.noteContentFragmentParent, "recyclerView_${args.note?.id}"
        )

        layout.backBtn.setOnClickListener {
            navController.popBackStack()
        }

        layout.saveNote.setOnClickListener {
            saveNote()
        }
        try {
            layout.etNoteContent.setOnFocusChangeListener { _, hasFocus ->
                if (hasFocus) {
                    layout.bottomBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    layout.etNoteContent.setStylesBar(layout.styleBar)
                } else layout.bottomBar.visibility = View.GONE

            }
        } catch (e: Throwable) {
            Log.d("TAG", "${e.stackTrace}")

            layout.fabColorPick.setOnClickListener {
                val bottomSheetDialog = BottomSheetDialog(
                    requireContext(),
                    R.style.BottomSheetDialogTheme
                )

                val bottomSheetView: View = layoutInflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.bottom_sheet_layout,
                    null
                )
                bottomSheetView.post {
                    bottomSheetDialog.behavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED
                }
                with(bottomSheetDialog)
                {
                    bottomSheetView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)
                    setContentView(bottomSheetView)
                    BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheetView).state =
                        BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED
                    val behavior: BottomSheetBehavior<*> =
                        BottomSheetBehavior.from<View>(bottomSheetView)
                    behavior.peekHeight = bottomSheetView.height
                    show()
                }
                bottomSheetDialog.show()

                val bottomSheetBinding = BottomSheetLayoutBinding.bind(bottomSheetView)
                bottomSheetBinding.apply {
                    colorPicker.apply {
                        setSelectedColor(color)
                        setOnColorSelectedListener { value ->
                            color = value
                            layout.apply {
                                noteContentFragmentParent.setBackgroundColor(color)
                                toolbarFragmentNoteContent.setBackgroundColor(color)
                                bottomBar.setBackgroundColor(color)
                                activity!!.window.statusBarColor = color
                            }
                            bottomSheetBinding.bottomSheetParent.setCardBackgroundColor(color)
                        }
                    }
                    bottomSheetParent.setCardBackgroundColor(color)
                }
                bottomSheetView.post {
                    bottomSheetDialog.behavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED
                }
            }

            //open with existing note item
            setUpNote()
        }
    }

    private fun setUpNote() {
        val note = args.note
        val title = layout.etTitle
        val content = layout.etNoteContent
        val lastEdited = layout.lastEdited

        if (note == null) {
            layout.lastEdited.text =
                getString(R.string.edited_on, SimpleDateFormat.getDateInstance().format(Date()))
        }
        if (note != null) {
            title.setText(note.title)
            content.renderMD(note.content)
            lastEdited.text = getString(R.string.edited_on, note.date)
            color = note.color
            layout.apply {
                CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
                    delay(10)
                    noteContentFragmentParent.setBackgroundColor(color)
                }
                toolbarFragmentNoteContent.setBackgroundColor(color)
                bottomBar.setBackgroundColor(color)
            }
            activity?.window?.statusBarColor = note.color
        }
    }

    private fun saveNote() {
        val navHostFragment =
            activity!!.supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainerView) as NavHostFragment
        val navController = navHostFragment.navController
        if (layout.etNoteContent.text.toString().isEmpty() || layout.etTitle.text.toString()
                .isEmpty()
        ) {
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Something is Empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        } else {
            note = args.note
            when (note) {
                null -> {
                    vm.saveNote(
                        NoteDataDetailsResponse(
                            0,
                            layout.etTitle.text.toString(),
                            layout.etNoteContent.getMD(),
                            currentData,
                            color
                        )
                    )
                    // moze niepotrzebne we can use flow
                    result = "Note Saved"
                    parentFragmentManager.setFragmentResult(
                        "key",
                        bundleOf("bundleKey" to result)
                    )

                    Log.d("note", "$note")
//                    navController.navigate(SaveUpdateFragmentDirections.actionSaveUpdateFragment2ToViewPagerFragment())
//
                    navController.popBackStack()
                }
                else -> {
                    updateNote()
                    navController.popBackStack()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun updateNote() {
        if (note != null) {
            vm.updateNote(
                NoteData(
                    note!!.id,
                    layout.etTitle.text.toString(),
                    layout.etNoteContent.getMD(),
                    currentData,
                    color
                )
            )

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In list adapter you shouldn't store the items in a field inside the adapter class if you want to access a specific item you can use this code:

```
currentList[position]
```

and when you want to update recycler view list just call this function:

```
adapter.submitList(newList)
```

list adapter will be handling the notifyDataSetChanges and you shouldn't call this function too.